# How to reposition UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have a UITableViewController and I want to add a navigation bar to it.  So after the navigation bar (which works fine), part of the original tableView is being covered up by the nav bar.

I tried to reposition the table view using this:

self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44 + 20 /* height of navbar + some margin */, 320, 416);

But the table won't position.

Comment: What is the superview of your `UINavigationBar`?  Is it your table view, your `UIWindow`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

`self.tableView.frame` doesn't work for me either, it throws an error, but

1. I set the `tableView` in `IB`
2. I create a caller in the h-file `IBOUTLET UITableView *myTabli;`
3. connect `FileOwner` and `tableView > myTabli` in `IB`
4. than I can call `myTabli.frame = CGRectframe(x,y,width,height);` in the m-File

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD set the nav bar as the header view of the table view like this (assuming you have the nav bar in a property called `navBar`):

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.navBar;
```

I am guessing this isn't what you want though (since the nav bar will scroll off when you scroll down the table).

Instead, you could change to a normal view controller & put the nav bar & a table view on its view (laid out however you want). You can add your own tableView property for the table view & make its data source & delegate your view controller & everything you have now should work just fine.